# How to call WordPress PHP file using external js file

Tags: php, wordpress

I have added custom PHP file in WordPress directory and added following line to use WordPress functions:

```
require ('../wp-blog-header.php');
```

Now I am able to use WordPress functions but unable call this file from javascript in ajax.

When I removed following line then I am able to call this file:

```
require ('../wp-blog-header.php');
```

Please suggest how can I solve this issue.

Comment: do you receive any errors while require string is present?

Comment: do you mean you put it directly in `wp-admin`, `wp-content` or `wp-includes`? If so, this is not really safe, because your file could be deleted on Wordpress update. It should be either in your template, or maybe outside of wordpress directory if there is one

Comment: @RafailAkhmetshin I am getting 404 (Not Found) error

Comment: @Kaddath thank you for advice. But still, I won't be able to access PHP file as I have added `wp-blog-header.php` file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

looks like this is standard behavior of WP

change

```
require ('../wp-blog-header.php');
```

to this line

```
require(dirname(__FILE__) . '../../wp-config.php'); //path to Your wp-config.php file

$wp->init();
$wp->parse_request();
$wp->query_posts();
$wp->register_globals();
//$wp->send_headers();
```

- here is source:
  https://cooltrainer.org/fixing-false-404-headers-on-external-pages-including-wp-blog-header-php/
- similar issue: https://serverfault.com/questions/451778/nginx-php-fpm-executes-script-but-returns-404